# Find parametric equations

Tags: parametric, curves

Find parametric equations for a particle moving two full revolutions clockwise around a circle of *radius* $2$ centered at $(3,-1)$. In other words give equations for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, and specify the time interval.

Is $x=3+2cost$
and $\ \ $$y=-1+2sint$

correct?

I only have several examples from class from which I can study .

it would be great if someone could provide detailed basic steps to solving this kind of problems

Thanks in advance .

Comment: That's the correct form (I'm not saying that's the answer they're looking for), but now you need to construct the equations in a way such that over some time interval (for instance, $t\in[0,1]$), a point on that curve makes two full **clockwise** revolutions.

Comment: what does a point on a curve that makes two full clockwise revolution mean ?

Comment: In your current equations, the particle starts at the point $(5,-1)$ (at $t=0$).  What you need to do now is modify the function so that after 1 second, the particle passes through $(5,-1)$ twice; in essence, you'll need to find the right periods for the $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ terms.  The other thing to be weary of is that in the equations you currently have, the particle wants to move in the **counterclockwise** direction; thus, you'll also need to do find a way to make the particle move **clockwise**.

Comment: can you direct me to some sort of basic function and knowledge ? or some website i could look at?

Comment: I would check out Paul's Online Math Notes on [Parametric Equations](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParametricEqn.aspx); in particular, pay attention to the difference between Examples 4 and 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Facts:**

**Q:** What is the equation of that circle using Cartesian coordinates?

**A:** As it centered in $(+3,-1)$ with radii $2$ so it is $$(x-3)^2+(y+1)^2=4$$

**Q:** Do the new relations I've got, satisfy the equation above? Will we have a right statement the?

**A:** As we have $x=3+2\cos(t),~~y=-1+2\sin(t)$ so $$(x-3)^2+(y+1)^2=4\cos^2(t)+4\sin^2(t)=4$$

**Q:** So, I have done it right?

**A:** Yes. you did it right. :-)

Comment: This is a Question and Answer site, after all! ;-) +1